# Monitoring Hadoop-metrics2 with Ganglia

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, ganglia

I have ganglia-3.6 installed and wants to monitor all the hadoop-metrics using it. I have followed the instructions from here: http://www.abcn.net/2014/05/install-and-config-ganglia-on-cdh5.html but not able to see any graphs related to hadoop-metrics2. I can see the default graphs about the hosts like disk usage,memory,CPU etc. but not any graphs related to hadoop-metrics. I am using cloudera-5(CDH5)

Comment: ganglia and hadoop are setup on ec2 environment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have made it working. Changes in conf files from command line does not work. So I had made changes from Cloudera Manager and it works.

Steps are:
Login to CM
HDFS -> Configuration -> Search for metric -> fill the text box of hadoop2-metrics field with instructions here:  http://www.abcn.net/2014/05/install-and-config-ganglia-on-cdh5.html

Repeat the above steps for Hbase and Yarn, then restart your cluster or related services, you will start seeing the metrics in ganglia and relative graphs as well.

Comment: I was trying the same but not sucessfull in getting metrics in ganglia. Im not getting the hadoop metric graphs in ganglia. Could you please update your metric screenshots  ?